# Book request in calculus

Tags: calculus

Could you please provide me with a book of calculus containing the concepts of trigonometry, hyperbolic functions, and complex numbers? thank you very much.

Comment: If you would like a nice first approach to more rigorous mathematics, Spivak's "Calculus" (which also covers complex numbers) is very well-written (an understatement, really) and quite standard.

Comment: Any newer version of other book please?